# Django forms have an "approved" field only available on the admin site and not the view?

Tags: django, forms

I'm learning django and would like to ask a question,
I have a simple form that asks the users for input and click submit, the admin receives an email when a form is submitted. I would like to have the admin approve/deny the form and save it.
I'm struggling with having the approve/deny selection only appears for the admin site. It wither papers for both admin and user or not showing for both.

```
request_status = (
        ('select', 'Select'),
        ('Approved', 'Approved'),
        ('Denied', 'Denied'),
        )
status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=request_status, default='select')
```

My models.py code is:

```
class SignUp(models.Model):
    ENV_CHOICE = (
        ('select', 'Select'),
        ('Production', 'Production'),
        ('Lab', 'Lab'),
        ('EBC_env', 'EBC_env'),
        ('Los_Angles', 'Los Angles'),
        )
    request_status = (
        ('select', 'Select'),
        ('Approved', 'Approved'),
        ('Denied', 'Denied'),
        ('Added_comment', 'Added_comment'),
        )
    email = models.EmailField()
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    what_is_the_change = models.TextField(max_length=250, null=True)
    environment = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=ENV_CHOICE,  default='select')
    models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=request_status, default='select', blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email
```

my forms.py code is:

```
class SignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SignUp
        fields = ('full_name', 'email', 'environment', 'what_is_the_change', 'change_date_and_time')
```

It shows model.CharField because my form is inheriting these fields. hopefully I'm making sense otherwise I would not know how to explain it better. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried `exclude = ("status",)` but also removes it from both admin and the form.

Comment: Add your `forms.py` and `admin.py` relevant code to your question too.

Answer (score 0):

In your forms.py assuming that you are using a modelform for your model. Ensure the Meta for the model does not include status in the 'fields'.

e.g.

If your model is ExampleModel in models.py:

```
class ExampleModel(models.Model):
    request_status = (
        ('select', 'Select'),
        ('Approved', 'Approved'),
        ('Denied', 'Denied'),
        )
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=request_status, default='select')
    user_input = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

And your forms.py is:

```
class ExampleModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ExampleModel
        fields = ('user_input',) #note the abscence of status
```

Should produce a form in admin with both fields, and a form in the user area with only the user input field.

Comment: Try excluding the status field in the Meta of the model form again and then in your admin.py explicitly name the fields you want. e.g. class ExampleModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin): fields=('status',...) and register it.

Comment: Did not work as well. The model admin complains that my `u"Key 'status' not found in 'SignUpForm'"`

Comment: I think I got it to work (Thanks @GeorginaS) my admin.py includes the fields: `fields = ('full_name', 'email', 'environment', 'what_is_the_change', 'change_date_and_time','status',)` and i removed status from the form and that did it.